# CONNECTIVITY_ISSUE uber api android

Tags: java, android, api

```
  config = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
            .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setRedirectUri("com.example.asus.uniontaxidouble.uberauth://redirect")
            .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX)
            .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS))
            .build();
    UberSdk.initialize(config);
    accessTokenStorage = new AccessTokenManager(this);
    Log.e("riderect URL", BuildConfig.REDIRECT_URI);
    LoginCallback loginCallback = new LoginCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLoginCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(AutorizationActivity.this, "onLoginCancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @SuppressLint("StringFormatInvalid")
        @Override
        public void onLoginError(@NonNull AuthenticationError error) {
            //   Toast.makeText(AutorizationActivity.this, error.name().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(AutorizationActivity.this, "Ошибка авторизации" + error.toStandardString().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoginSuccess(@NonNull AccessToken accessToken) {
            loadProfileInfo();
        }

        @SuppressLint("StringFormatInvalid")
        @Override
        public void onAuthorizationCodeReceived(@NonNull String authorizationCode) {
            Toast.makeText(AutorizationActivity.this, authorizationCode.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    };


    loginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenStorage, loginCallback, config,LOGIN_BUTTON_CUSTOM_REQUEST_CODE);
    if (accessTokenStorage.getAccessToken() == null) {
        loginManager.setRedirectForAuthorizationCode(true);
        loginManager.login(this);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Вход в авторизацию", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Сразу предупреждаю что зарегистрировал url перенаправления в панели управления ube. Выходит ошибка в AuthenticationError CONNECTIVITY_ISSUE  как говорит документация "При попытке загрузки произошла ошибка подключения" помогите пожалуйста что-делаю не так!!!!

Comment: а что за АПИ от Убера что дает ? для чего  ?

Comment: Это авторизация